# How to force widow lines using \widowpenalty?

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

Suppose I want the last line of a paragraph to be printed on a new page to have a widow line.
Which command is suitable for this?
Neither `\widowpenalty` nor `\clubpenalty` works for this.
I do not want use `\newpage`.

**EDIT**
I've given this to LaTeX but only 0 is on the first page.
I thought it should be 0,9 and 1, and only after 1 should be newpage?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
0\\
9\\
1\\
2\\
{\clubpenalty-10000 \par }
2\\
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
{\widowpenalty-10000 \par}
4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444\\
5\\
5\\
7\\
{\widowpenalty-10000 \par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want that 0, 9, and 1 on the first page, and 2 alone atop the second (that is, if you want the *last* line of a paragraph to be detached from the others), you want a *widow* line (one that “has its past behind”), not an *orphan* line (one that “has its future ahead”).  But note that you should remove ``\\`` from what you mean to be the last line, otherwise an additional, empty line will follow.

Comment: @GuM Your intention seems right to me (what you say about "2 alone atop") but it'll be nice if you could specify the code which achieves this.I cannot deduce the code from your English description.

Comment: (Untested): `0\\9\\1\\2 {\widowpenalty = -10000 \par}`.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: what’s the purpose of this?  Why do you want to have the last line of a paragraph on a new page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is not an orphan line, but a *widow* line. An orphan line is when the first line of a paragraph is separated from the rest of the paragraph by a page break.

Just set `\widowpenalty` to –infinity (which is `-10000`). This will tell TeX that that is the best place to break the page.

If you want this to affect the entire document, then just write `\widowpenalty-10000`:

> [image]

Otherwise, if you want to limit the scope of this assignment to a single paragraph, you need to do it inside a group and make sure that the paragraph ends (with a `\par` or a blank line) before the group ends, or `\widowpenalty` will have no effect:

> [image]

MWE for the first picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\widowpenalty-10000
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

MWE for the second picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
{\widowpenalty-10000 \par}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

You need the `\par` inside the same group as `\widowpenalty-10000` because otherwise TeX would restore the value of `\widowpenalty` to its original value before it breaks the paragraph into lines, and the value of `\widowpenalty` TeX uses for the current paragraph is the one in force at the time the paragraph is broken into lines.

Comment: Dear Phelype, this is what I did. But please note that I want to have after your `anim id est laborum` **another text** and another continuing paragraph so that this very line becomes a real **orphan** with some text after it!

Comment: @user2925716 Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean... You mean you want the effect of `\widowpenalty-10000` to end after the first paragraph?

Comment: I want to have a real orphan. That is a last line of some paragraph from the first page on the second page on the top followed by another paragraph on the second page. **And this should be done for every existing page.** If you need more explanation please ask me.

Comment: @user2925716 I'm not sure what you mean by "a real orphan". See if the edit answers your question.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it. I just need to understand your code now.  And I also mean that this should happen for each page: for the second as did for the first.

Comment: I'd do `{\widowpenalty-10000 \par}` instead of bracing the whole paragraph.

Comment: @user2925716 I added an explanation for the two versions and egreg's suggestion

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik After all this, how/when can I use `\clubpenalty` in a manner different from `\widowpenalty` ?

Comment: @user2925716 I just realised that what you want is a _widow_, not an orphan line :-) `\clubpenalty` is the same as `\widowpenalty`. `\clubpenalty` is inserted between the first and second lines in a paragraph and `\widowpenalty` is inserted between then the second-to-last and last lines in a paragraph. However it seems that in LaTeX setting `\clubpenalty` doesn't work as expected...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, and what about the ending `\par`: is this the same for `\clubpenalty` as it were for `\widowpenalty` ? Or, on the contrary, can it be ommited with `\clubpenalty` ?

Comment: @user2925716 Yes, it is the same. Both `\clubpenalty` and `\widowpenalty` are taken into account when TeX breaks the paragraph into lines. You need the `\par` with both.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Please see the **EDIT** in my OP.

Comment: @user2925716 See GuM's comment below your question. You are mixing widows and orphans (for instance, the code I show produces widow lines).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I have deleted all instances of `\widowpenalty` but still `\begin{document}
0\\
9\\
1
{5\\2 \clubpenalty-10000 \par}
2\\` produces only 0 at 1st page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101094/discussion-between-phelype-oleinik-and-user2925716).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Phelype, can you have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521867/a-problem-with-colors-in-winedt) ?

Comment: @user2925716 I don't have WinEdt nor Adobe Acrobat to check the problem. Sorry, I can't help you with this one...