# A problem with colors in WinEdt

Tags: pdftex

I have a problem with colors in WinEdt.
When I compile the MWE below in WinEdt, the text

> this becomes a link

is correctly green.

But when I save it as a pdf file, then the color becomes incorrectly
**black**, though the clickability correctly persists.

```
%&latex
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\documentclass[14pt]{book}
\topmargin 2mm
\oddsidemargin 10mm
\evensidemargin 10mm
\textwidth 150mm
\textheight 220mm

\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
%\usepackage{czech}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{theorem}

\usepackage[pdftex,breaklinks,colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,pdftitle={Lecture 9},pdfauthor={Ryan Higginbottom},linkcolor=green,pdfsubject={LaTeX}]{hyperref}

%\makeindex


\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}


\begin{document}
Links\hyperlink{foo_1}{This becomes a link}.
\hypertarget{foo_2}{This is the target}.
\newpage



\hypertarget{foo_1}{This is the target}.
Links\hyperlink{foo_2}{This becomes a link}.



\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save as pdf"?. Your example can not be tested as it contains inputs we don't have.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See my **EDIT**, is it better now ? I mean when I save "save as pdf" from the menu of Acrobat.

Comment: Why should you do this? You already have a pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But when I open that pdf file by clickinmg on it from the place where it is saved then it is also **not** green. It is green only after the compilation from WinEdt. Why ?

Comment: you have tagged this as xetex and winedt but it does not seem to be related to either (I assume from the code that you are using pdflatex?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've just checked it. I'm really using "pdflatex".

Comment: Your file begins `%&latex` which (on systems that use that line at all) would make it use latex not pdflatex.

Comment: If I run the posted code with pdflatex i get `! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `pdftex',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.`

Answer (score 1):

the first line

```
 %&latex
```

forces the pdflatex to act like latex, in dvi mode, not like pdflatex, as such if you run pdflatex on the file then you get the error

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `pdftex',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
```

and no usable output.

If you delete that line it runs without error and produces

[image]

As you see here it is best to avoid driver options like `[pdftex`  as `hyperref` will choose a suitable driver if you do not force it to use the wrong one,

Comment: I've used this and it still gives the black color upon opening the pdf file by mouse: \documentclass[14pt]{book}

%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
%dd& latex

\topmargin 2mm
\oddsidemargin 10mm
\evensidemargin 10mm
\textwidth 150mm
\textheight 220mm

\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
%\usepackage{czech}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{theorem}

\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,pdftitle={Lecture 9},pdfauthor={Ryan Higginbottom},linkcolor=green,pdfsubject={LaTeX}]{hyperref}

Comment: Which part should be deleted here ? I've disabled &latex command.and \hyperref[pdftex ....

Comment: If you just delete the first line of the document in the question and use pdflatex then you will get green links. Are you sure you are checking the correct pdf?

Comment: I do get green links after running pdflatex from WInedt. But when I click (from TotalCommander) on the resulting pdf file, I get black ones.I'm clicking on the right file by checking its time creation.

Comment: winedt is an editor you use to write the file. it will run pdflatex (or latex) on the file and generate a pdf. The editor used to write the file is not relevant. I can not guess what you mean by "green links after running pdflatex from WInedt"  where are these links appearing and what pdf viewer are you using to see them?

Comment: You have given to me a good hint. When I open that file in "GSView" then the green links continue to exist. But not so in pdf Acrobat Reader. They are black in it. Do you happen know why?